# Convert date to milliseconds gives me wrong date java

Tags: java, android, datetime, converters, simpledateformat

I want to convert the following datetime do milliseconds :

> 17/07/2015 13:30

For this I have used the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm");
Date d = null;
try {
    d = f.parse(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
}
long milliseconds = d.getTime();
```

But when this date I add to the calendar in Android it seems that the date is 17 of January not 17 of July.

Comment: "mm" means minutes - so `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm` should almost certainly be `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm`. Note the change from `hh` to `HH` too. See http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/05/05/common-mistakes-in-datetime-formatting-and-parsing/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be like this :-

`SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");` with `MM` for months not `mm` for minutes & `HH` for 24-Hours instead of `hh` for am/pm Hours

Comment: I suspect the OP also wants HH instead of hh.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `mm` for your month to `MM`.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you have typo in date format `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm` it should be `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm` now please have look into my code and [dateformate](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for android

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
 String input = "17/07/2015 13:30";
 Date datestr = formatter.parse(input);

 **long date = datestr.getTime();** // what you want 

// revers of your Date  

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(datestr.getTime());
String output = formatter.format(calendar.getTime())
```